# Does JScript support string trim method?

Tags: windows, wsh, jscript, windows-scripting

Whilst developing a Windows procedure using JScript, it seems that some string methods fail to work. In this example using trim, line 3 generates the runtime error:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

My code:

```js
strParent = "  a  ";
strParent = strParent.trim();
WScript.Echo ("Value: " + strParent);
```

Am I being stupid?
Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 6):

JScript running under the Windows Scripting Host uses an old version of JScript based off of ECMAScript 3.0. The [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function was introduced in ECMAScript 5.0.

Comment: Thanks v. much Cheran.  Back to the drawing board then!

Answer (score 5):

You can add `trim` to the String class:

### trim-test.js

```
String.prototype.trim = function()
{
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
};

strParent = "  a  ";
strParent = strParent.trim();
WScript.Echo ("Value: " + strParent);
```

### Output from cmd.exe

```
C:\>cscript //nologo trim-test.js
Value: a
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a polyfill, for example this one:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill

This snippet:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
strParent = "  a  ";
strParent = strParent.trim();
WScript.Echo ("Value: '" + strParent + "'");
```

will output

```
Value: 'a'
```